# Let $B = (B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a standard brownian motion and $I_t = \inf_{0 \leq s \leq t} B_s$, show $F(t, B_t, I_t)$ is a martingale.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales, finance

Let $B = (B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a standard brownian motion and $I_t = \inf_{0 \leq s \leq t} B_s$, show that

$F(t, B_t, I_t) = (B_t−I_t)^6−15t(B_t−I_t)^4+45t^2(B_t−I_t)^2−15t^3$

is a martingale. I'm really not sure where to begin with this, any pointers would be appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

The application of Ito's formula may look intimidating, but it's not too bad. The $dB_t$ terms will combine into a martingale, so it suffices to check that the $dt$ and $dI_t$ terms cancel each other out. In fact, the combined $dI_t$ terms  vanish because $B_t-I_t$ vanishes at points of decrease of $I_t$ and the partial derivative of $F(t,x,y)$ with respect to $y$  vanishes whenever $x=y$. This leaves only the $dt$ terms
$$
F_t(t,B_t,I_t)dt + {1\over 2} F_{xx}(t,B_t,I_t) dt, 
$$
which I will leave to you.

Comment: What if the $I_t=\sup_{0 \leq s \leq t} B_s?$ @JohnDawkins, Because then I can't say $dI_t$ term vanish.